# Set which grub loader to use after dual booting two linux OSes

Tags: grub2

I installed a second Linux distro recently which replaced the old grub that was already in place with its own fresh installation. I would like keep using the grub loader from the first OS, Ubuntu.

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: The second Linux installation stopped working and I wish to install Arch Linux in a new partition, until I free up the rest of the partitions. I have had trouble getting the Arch Linux live CD to boot from my USB key so I am trying to use grml-rescueboot to boot from the iso. Since the current boot loader is set to the second Linux installation, any change I make to the boot loader right now is useless until I can set it to use this grub. Sorry, lengthy comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First boot into the Ubuntu version that you want to want to use the grub loader from.

After that run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

replacing `sda` with the harddrive your BIOS uses as default boot device.

You probably want to run `sudo update-grub` as well, so your Ubuntu installation scans the available boot options and adds the second distro.

There are two things to keep in mind:

1. If you get a kernel-upgrade after booting your new distro, that will not show up until `update-grub` has run on your old Ubuntu.
2. If your new distro is on `btrfs` with subvolumes, and your Ubuntu doesn't know how to interpret `btrfs` partitions with subvolumes then the new distro will not show up in the grub boot options unless you update `find-btrfs` in `/etc/grub.d` to handle that.

Comment: How do you list which boot-loader the BIOS currently uses?

Comment: That statement is years old and I forgot to delete it in the meantime. There were a ton of things that disturbed me about stackoverflow in the past. I do not want to go into details. Anyway that statement from me is years old and I removed it. Thank you for pointing that out.